# Moving between two different contiguous containers

Tags: c++11, stl, move, move-constructor, boost-container

I have a `std::vector<double>` that I have to move to a `boost::container::flat_set<double>`. 
Both containers are contiguous, so after sorting the vector in principle I could move the data from one to the other.

**Is there a way to move the whole data between these two different containers?**

Please, take into account that I want to move the whole data, not element by element.

I can move data between containers of the same type, but not between different containers.

```
std::vector<double>  v1 = ...
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());

std::vector<double>  v2(std::move(v1)); // ok
boost::flat_set<double> f2(v1.begin(), v1.end()); // doesn't move, it copies
boost::flat_set<double> f3(std::move(v1)); // doesn't compile
```

It seems that for this to work `flat_set` should have a move constructor from containers with `.data()`, where the pointer is stolen from the argument.

Comment: probably there isn't. but since the underlying type is a primitive one, `memcpy` the data from one container to another shouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: By the way, copying and moving PODs is the same thing. I've given general answer for your general question without reading too deep, thinking that `double` is just for example. Seems your problem is more specific and I'd call "How to inject `std::vector` data into `boost::flat_set`?"

Comment: [std::move_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)

Comment: @Caleth,  I think that will only move element by element, but not the entire data block

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some way to verify whenever data alignment in both containers match and `memcpy` could be used (and source cleared without destructing) exists and maybe someone will share it with us, but as long as we want to use STL there is a way: the `std::move_iterator`. It makes your container constructor move elements instead of copying. It does not remove elements out of source container though, but leaves them `stateless` (e.g. empty strings as in example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::string>  v1 = {"a","v","d"};
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());

    std::vector<std::string>  v2(std::move(v1)); // ok
    boost::container::flat_set<std::string> f1(std::make_move_iterator(v2.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v2.end())); // moves, but does not remove elements from of source container


    for(auto& s : v1)
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << ' ';
    std::cout << " <- v1 \n";

    for(auto& s : v2)
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << ' ';
    std::cout << " <- v2 \n";

    for(auto& s : f1)
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << ' ';
    std::cout << " <- f1 \n";
}
```

Output

```
 <- v1 
'' '' ''  <- v2 
'a' 'd' 'v'  <- f1
```

Online code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZLbocXKdqYHT0zYi

Comment: Thanks, sorry but that is not moving the data. It moves element by element. Among other things moving in this case should be a O(1) operation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible without modifying the constructor `boost::container::flat`. 
Without modifying either class it seems that the only a hack would do it, for example using `reinterpret_cast`.
The solution I found is either to use an alternative implementation of `vector` or very ugly code.

> Before going into my solution, I must that say that this is probably a
>   defect of both classes. These clases should have a set of
>   `release()`/`aquire(start, end)` functions that respectively
>   returns the pointer range to the data releasing the ownership and 
>   gets the pointer range owning it from then on. An alternative could be to
>   have a constructor that moves from any other container that has a the
>   data member function.

#### Solution using `reinterpret_cast` and a different implementation of `vector`

It turns out that `reinterpret_cast`ing from `std::vector` to `boost::container::flat_set` is not possible, because the layout is not compatible. 
However it is possible to reinterpret_cast from `boost::container::vector` to `boost::container::flat_set` out of the box (that is because they have a common implementation).

```
#include<cassert>
#include<boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

int main(){
    boost::container::vector<double> v = {1.,2.,3.};
    boost::container::flat_set<double> fs = std::move(reinterpret_cast<boost::container::flat_set<double>&>(v));

    assert(v.size() == 0);
    assert(*fs.find(2.) == 2.);s
    assert(fs.find(4.) == fs.end());
}
```

So, I can replace `std::vector` by `boost::container::vector` and I can move data to a `flat_set`.

#### Non-portable solution using `std::vector` and ugly code

The reason the layout of `std::vector` and `boost::container::vector` are different is that `boost::container::vector` stores metadata in this way:

```
class boost::container::vector{
   pointer     m_start;
   size_type   m_size;
   size_type   m_capacity;
}
```

while `std::vector` (in GCC) is basically pure pointers,

```
class std::vector{
    pointer _M_start;
    pointer _M_finish;
    pointer _M_end_of_storage;
}
```

So, my conclusion is that moving is possible only through a hack given that the implementation I use of `std::vector` is not compatible with `boost::container::flat_set`.

In an extreme case, one can do this (sorry if this code offends someone, the code is not portable):

```
template<class T>
boost::container::flat_set<T> to_flat_set(std::vector<T>&& from){
//  struct dummy_vector{T* start; T* finish; T* end_storarge;}& 
//      dfrom = reinterpret_cast<dummy_vector&>(from);
    boost::container::flat_set<T> ret;
    struct dummy_flat_set{T* start; std::size_t size; std::size_t capacity;}& 
        dret = reinterpret_cast<dummy_flat_set&>(ret); 
    dret = {from.data(), from.size(), from.capacity()};
//  dfrom.start = dfrom.finish = dfrom.end_storarge = nullptr;
    new (&from) std::vector<T>();
    return ret;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<double> v = {1.,2.,3.};
    boost::container::flat_set<double> fs = to_flat_set(std::move(v));

    assert(v.size() == 0);
    assert(*fs.find(2.) == 2.);
    assert(fs.find(4.) == fs.end());
}
```

*Note that I am not taking into account allocator issues at all. I am not sure how to handle allocators here.*

In retrospect I don't mind using a form of `cast` for this specific problem, because somehow I have to tell that the vector is sorted before moving to `flat_set`. (The problem is that this goes to extreme because it is a `reinterpret_cast`.)
However this is a secondary issue, there should be legal way to move from `std::vector` to `boost::container::vector`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is UB behavior even in the case where you say it's ok.

Comment: @bolov , Are you talking about the sentence "It is possible to `reinterpret_cast` from `boost::container::vector` to `boost::container::flat_set` out of the box". I am curious, why do you say that  is UB?

Comment: @bolov, exactly, aliasing rules, gcc gives a warning. Do you know if it can be worked around here? Do you think that putting `flat_set<T> ret` in the heap will help? (I will loose RVO but that is not a major problem.)

Comment: no, it can't be worked around. The ideal solution would be for the containers to have a `release` and an `acquire` methods to access the underlying buffer and alocator. Since that is not the case I would recommend using `std::move` (from algorithm) with iterators. Don't bother with tricks like explicitly calling `memcpy`. Only types for which `is_trivially_copyable` is true can be copied with `memcpy`. A decent compiler will do these tricks for you (with optimizations enabled of course) when it is legal to do so.

Comment: @bolov, I agree I think `release` should return some kind pointer allocator pair or some smart pointer with allocator information. or a shared_ptr/unique_ptr where the allocator is type-erased or something. Which brings the point, there should be some kind of pointer allocator pair class.

Comment: @bolov Using std::move on the interator doesn't help much, simple object will be still copied instead of moved.

Comment: I have be reading about strict aliasing and, from what I understand, it is considered more acceptable to do this casting through a `union`. I understand it is still UB, but apparently it is a "better" UB. https://web.archive.org/web/20171221170757/http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html